# Migrating from Syncfusion to DevExpress controls

Tags: c#, devexpress, syncfusion, devexpress-windows-ui

My existing application is using Syncfusion controls v10.104.0.44 but now due to some syncfusion support contract renewal issues we are migrating our application to DevExpress controls. I am trying to check feasibility for replacing the controls but I can see there are some properties/events which are not there in Devexpress controls.

For example to replace Syncfusion windows Grid control I am using XtraGrid with GridControlNavigator and I could not find the below properties:
navigator properties>>
navControl.AllowAddNew
navControl.MaxRecord
navControl.ShowVerticalScrollBar
navControl.SplitBars
navControl.ThemesEnabled

Grid properties>>
gridControl.FillSplitterPane
gridControl.ListBoxSelectionMode
gridControl.NumberedColHeaders
gridControl.NumberedRowHeaders
gridControl.Properties.RowHeaders
gridControl.ColCount
gridControl.RowCount
gridControl.SerializeCellsBehavior
gridControl.SmartSizeBox

Grid events>>
gridControl.QueryRowCount
gridControl.QueryCellInfo
gridControl.QueryCanMergeCells
gridControl.SaveCellInfo
gridControl.PrepareViewStyleInfo
gridControl.CurrentCellActivated
gridControl.SaveCellFormattedText 
gridControl.CurrentCellDeactivated
gridControl.CurrentCellValidating

I have also tried to find properties/events with similar name which will ultimately provide the same functionality but couldn't. Could you please check if these properties/events are available. And is there any list of mapping between Syncfusion controls properties and DevExpress??

Comment: I work for Syncfusion. Please let me know if you need any clarifications regarding the Syncfusion controls subscription. Thanks.

Comment: I realize this question is very old...  I recognize some of these properties and can map them, if it helps, but I also realize it may be possible it's no longer relevant since it was August when you were asking.  Let me know if you still need to know